# Create a timeline from non-continuous data in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have data from my bank in a table. The table contains all postings and a balance. The problem is if there is no posting on a date then there is no entry and hence no balance.

I would like to get a table out with all dates (e.g. today and a year back) for each account. Then I will join exchange rates and sum each day, so I have a "bank total balance" per day.

Here's my table with sample data (simplified, only relevant columns, except Amount which is included to make understanding the table easier):

| Id | Account | Currency | Date | Amount | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | EUR | 2024-02-10 | 100 | 550 |
| 101 | 1 | EUR | 2024-02-10 | 15 | 565 |
| 102 | 2 | USD | 2024-02-10 | 50 | 420 |
| 103 | 1 | EUR | 2024-02-10 | 13 | 578 |
| 104 | 1 | EUR | 2024-02-11 | -8 | 570 |
| 105 | 1 | EUR | 2024-02-12 | 310 | 880 |
| 106 | 1 | EUR | 2024-02-12 | -50 | 830 |

The balance for the day is always the one with the highest Id.

Desired output:

| Date | Currency | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-10 | EUR | 578 |
| 2024-02-10 | USD | 420 |
| 2024-02-11 | EUR | 570 |
| 2024-02-11 | USD | 420 |
| 2024-02-12 | EUR | 830 |
| 2024-02-12 | USD | 420 |

I do have a table of dates (don't know if that's necessary).

I've tried a lot but simply can't figure out how to do it.

I've come this far:

```
SELECT Date, Currency, Balance
FROM bank
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id
  FROM bank
  WHERE Account IN (1, 2)
  GROUP BY Date, Currency
 )
```

Comment: have you considered to create a reference table full of dates and join it with your query? if you don't want reference table, you can [generate the dates on the fly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql) for the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of my comment is roughly this way:

```
with currencies as (
  select distinct(currency) as currency from bank
),
curr_dates as (
  select *
  from dates as d
  join currencies
  where `date` between '2024-02-10' and '2024-02-12'
)
select *,
  (
    select balance
    from bank as b
    where b.`date` <= cd.`date`
      and b.currency = cd.currency
      and b.account in (1, 2)
    order by b.id desc
    limit 1
  ) as balance
from curr_dates as cd
order by date;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gt9sEP9YX7Y4zteae6ddk1/2

It outputs:

| date | currency | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-10 | EUR | 578 |
| 2024-02-10 | USD | 420 |
| 2024-02-11 | EUR | 570 |
| 2024-02-11 | USD | 420 |
| 2024-02-12 | EUR | 830 |
| 2024-02-12 | USD | 420 |

It might not be performant, unfortunately there is no given answer that produce the desired result in the answer.

Also, i do wonder why on earth `EUR` for `2024-02-10` is `565` (row `101`) instead of `578` (row `103`) is it a mistake?

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Takes 2,5 seconds to run with dates for a year which I think is acceptable.
Also, you are right about what I wrote as desired output. I have changed my original post to be correct.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SimonGade glad be of help. I was hesitant when I wrote my answer not quite sure if its the correct output given the description. however, I put it anyway given the other answer hardly anything close to the expected output. btw, you could replace the CTE for `currencies` if you have a currency table - it should be faster using it instead of throwing `distinct` on un-indexed column.

Comment: It's quite fast regarding `currencies`. What makes it slow is `ORDER BY Id` but I don't think there's anything to do about that.

Comment: @SimonGade you are right, it might be even slower if the subquery evaluated for each date-currency pairs even though it only have a single value (e.g. `USD` in the sample data). i do wonder if a `left join lateral` will be faster..

Comment: `left lateral join`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gt9sEP9YX7Y4zteae6ddk1/4

Answer (score 1):

You want a [Window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). These operate over a range of rows and can perform different functionality like aggregating the data from them, or taking the max value.

You want something like:

```
SELECT * MAX(balance) OVER(PARTITION BY currency, date)
FROM bank
ORDER BY date
```

If you order the query correctly you could use LAST_VALUE instead of MAX.

Comment: i believe your answer misses a comma and it won't produce `USD` for `2024-02-11` and `2024-02-12`

Answer (score 0):

Here we can see how a date range can be selected between two dates of your choice which can be then left-joined with your table. In the example below I used an ad-hoc table to join with, instead, you may `left join sample on sample.Date = v.selected_date` instead:

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
 left join (select 1 as foo) t
 on 1=1
where selected_date between '2023-02-16' and '2024-02-16'
```